# Add additional fields to form after click - the node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have a form in which I need to add a button that will allow the user to add a new field.

I'm trying to do it with JavaScript, but since I don't know much this language I'm lost with some concepts.

The form I use is one where the data is completed in steps, and the fields I want to add are the following

```html
<div class="job-form row mb-3">
                
    {% for form in add_trabajo %}

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="ref" class="">Nombre</label>
        {% render_field form.trabajo class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ej: Reparación de envolvente delantero" %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="ref" class="">Descuento</label>
        {% render_field form.descuento class="form-control" type="text" %}
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-2">
        <label for="ref" class="">Precio</label>
        {% render_field form.precio class="form-control" type="text" %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 d-flex align-items-end">
        <button id="addButton" type="button" class="btn-icon btn-icon-only btn btn-success p-2"><i class="pe-7s-plus btn-icon-wrapper"> </i></button>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
</div>
```

I'm trying to add these fields after existing ones that are identical
[image]

I already have the button and some code in javascript but it indicates the following error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before 
which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at HTMLButtonElement.addForm
```

This is my JavaScript code

```js
let jobForm = document.querySelectorAll(".job-form")
let container = document.querySelector("#presupuestoForm") 
let addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton")
let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_trabajosarealizar_set-TOTAL_FORMS")
let formNum = jobForm.length-1 // Get the number of the last form on the page with zero-based indexing

  
addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)
  
function addForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  let newForm = jobForm[0].cloneNode(true) //Clone the bird form
  let formRegex = RegExp(`trabajosarealizar_set-(\\d){1}-`,'g') //Regex to find all instances of the form number
  
  formNum++ //Increment the form number
  newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `trabajosarealizar_set-${formNum}-`) //Update the new form to have the correct form number

  container.insertBefore(newForm, addButton) //Insert the new form at the end of the list of forms
  
 
  
  totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`) //Increment the number of total forms in the management form
}
```

and this would be the structure of my form

[image]

that's where I try to add the new fields, between the job-form class and the divider with id div-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means *"`addButton` is not a child of `container`"*.

The nodes to provide are `parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`.

`parentNode` has to be the direct parent of the `referenceNode`.

So try:

```
jobForm.parentNode.insertBefore(newForm, addButton)
```

But that may not be correct either... since `#addButton` is a child of `.job-form`... I think that will have two add buttons.

But now that you know what [.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) needs... You can fix it.